# Python: Unable to use for loop in textfiles

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
print("writing text to file")
prompt = '>'
data = [input(prompt) for i in range(3)]

with open('textfile.txt', 'w') as testfile:
    testfile.write("\n".join(data))

with open('textfile.txt', 'r') as testfile:
    print (testfile.read())
    data = [line.strip('\n') for line in testfile]
    data2 = testfile.readlines()

print(data)
print(data2)
```

After learning how to read and write from text files I have been trying to use

```
for line in textfile
```

But to no avail. In my above code both data and data2 print as empty arrays which makes me think I am doing something really wrong. Before I could get testfile.readlines() to work but I was never able to use a for loop. For some reason it wouldn't even enter the loop (even if I do a standard for loop outside of list comprehension).

Does anyone have any ideas what I am doing incorrectly? I could not find anyone else who has this problem.

Comment: `textfile` and `testfile` are two different things, is that your problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you called

```
    print (testfile.read())
```

That put the file pointer to the end of the file.  You need to bring it back to the beginning again by calling

```
    testfile.seek(0)
```

After that, so that when the next file reading method is called it will be able to read the file from the beginning again.  Likewise, after that list comprehension assignment to `data` you will need to do the same so that `data2` can be populated.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you do is `print(testfile.read())` which reads the entire contents of the file. After that any read is going to fail. You need to seek back to the beginning of the file:

```
testfile.seek(0)
```